# Using lambda to select top 1 row returned from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable, datarow

I have a DataTable called currencyAmounts and using lambda, my expression was working fine until the return had more than one possibility. I am searching the DataTable for a match to my "value" variable. How can I change the following expression to just select the first row returned:

```
DataRow resultRow = currencyAmounts.AsEnumerable().Single(r => ((decimal)r["OriginalAmount"]) == value);
```

I am getting the following error when this is run:

> Sequence contains more than one matching element

Comment: The Error message explains it all actually. Single() throw exception when there are more than one matching element within the condition.(or there is no element)

Comment: Using `Single()` denotes that the resultset should contain 1 element. Use `FirstOrDefault()` if you want to get the first from a sequence.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, Barry. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Error message explains it all actually. Single() throw exception when there are more than one matching element within the condition.(or there is no element). You should use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`

```
DataRow resultRow = currencyAmounts.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault(r => ((decimal)r["OriginalAmount"]) == value);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `First` instead of `Single`

Answer (score 0):

You can change the "Single()" with a "First()".

That's because single (from the microsoft page) "Returns the only element of a sequence, and throws an exception if there is not exactly one element in the sequence."

Answer (score 0):

Single will throw an error if there are more or less than 1 element in the collection.

If you want the first, and are sure there is always at least one result, use

```
.Single();
```

If you are not sure there is always at least one result, use

```
.SingleOrDefault();
```